# How to return only a selection of results from mongodb with the golang mongo-driver

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

I would like to create an array of objects but only with a filtered list of key-values.

```golang
    collection, err := driver.GetDBCollection()

    cur, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.D{{}})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var results []primitive.M
    for cur.Next(context.Background()) {
        var result bson.M
        e := cur.Decode(&result)
        if e != nil {
            log.Fatal(e)
        }
        results = append(results, result)

    }
```

Lets say my data in mongodb looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "123456",
        "username": "username1",
        "password": "hashedPassword",
        "token": "theToken"
    },
    {
        "_id": "123456",
        "username": "username2",
        "password": "hashedPassword",
        "token": "theToken"
    },
    {
        "_id": "123456",
        "username": "username3",
        "password": "hashedPassword",
        "token": "theToken"
    },
    {
        "_id": "123456",
        "username": "username4",
        "password": "hashedPassword",
        "token": "theToken"
    }
]
```

What i currently have above will return all of that but if i didn't want to expose some fields, how would i return all results from just selected keys, for example not including the password and token, like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "123456",
        "username": "username1"
    },
    {
        "_id": "123456",
        "username": "username2"
    },
    {
        "_id": "123456",
        "username": "username3"
    },
    {
        "_id": "123456",
        "username": "username4"
    }
]
```

ref:
https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo

Comment: Have you considered the 'projection' [findOption](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/find/#find)?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who cannot find this, here is the solution, its not very well documented:

```golang
    opts := options.Find().SetProjection(bson.M{
        "_id":       1,
        "username":  1,
    })
    cur, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.D{{}}, opts)
```